# Date range queries for Custom Properties

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

While capturing I set a custom property `CREATED` like:

```
* Mynote
:PROPERTIES:
:CREATED: [2017-10-12 17:40]
:END:
```

How can I create an agenda view which contains all the Items I created this week?

(I am aware of `file+olp+datetree` to capture items in a datetree but I regulary refile them to a "proper" location, so this tree doesn't help me)

Comment: There are a few `org-mode` gurus who are passionate about these types of questions and will probably come along any minute to answer your question.  While I am aware that `org-tags-view` can query drawers as discussed in the advanced searching section of the `org-mode` manual, that function doesn't specialize in date ranges.  You might wish to consider using a regexp that contains a match of the seven target days, and perform an advanced search as discussed in the manual.  `org-search-view` is another option that accepts regex.    I don't know of a way off-hand to use `org-agenda-list` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare dates using the usual comparason operators (for example `<`) in queries.  Further you can refer to relative times using the syntax `<-1w>` for "one week ago" (especially useful is the special value `<today>`).  For example `CREATED>"<-1w>"` will match anything whose `CREATED` property is greater than one week ago (entries without the property don't match).  Both active and inactive times will match.